# Logging to AWS Cloudwatch using Serilog in .Net core 5.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, .net-core, amazon-cloudwatch, serilog

I am new to .Net Core 5.0, I am unable to find any suitable guide to check how to setup logging to Cloudwatch using Serilog.

Currently, in our application, we are logging to file & console using Serilog. Now the requirement is to log in Cloudwatch also. Existing configuration is in appsettings.Development.json file where we have a section called "Serilog" which contains the "writeTo" section. Can anyone guide me how to set up logging in Cloudwatch using appsettings.json file ??

Comment: maybe this one helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53321096/how-to-configure-a-serilog-sink-for-logging-to-cloudwatch

Comment: It's not so much in detail. I would like to have a detailed answer like which packages to use, how & where to store the AWS credentials (don't know whether needed or not) & then how to configure everything.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS.Logger.SeriLog NuGet package provides a SeriLog sink that will send the log messages to CloudWatch Logs. The package is on GitHub with more information on how to use. https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet#serilog

Comment: I am using appsettings.json file where I have that Serilog node with other properties. I am getting confused on one thing that is "Do I need to pass AWS credentials? If yes, then what credentials are needed & also how to configure that part?"

Answer (score 0):

Pre-requisite: configure your aws credentials on your local machine.
Please read aws documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html

once you have your credentials file ready locally, then

1. Add nuget reference to your project: **AWS.Logger.Serilog**
2. I am supposing you are initializing your logger from configuration. In this case make sure you init the Serilog logger in your startup, after the app builder is created:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
        .CreateLogger();
```

3. Make sure to configure your appsetting Serilog section like this:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "AWS.Logger.SeriLog"
    ],
    "LogGroup": "YOUR_AWS_LOG_GROUP",
    "Region": "YOUR_AWS_REGION",
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "AWSSeriLog"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Check the samples here:

https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet/blob/master/samples/Serilog/SerilogTestCodeFromConfig/appsettings.json

Comment: Marco Merola, please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: It's just a matter of reading the code in Github... The samples are already there.

Comment: @Marco yes, but the gihub example might be deleted in the future, or blocked in some countries. Now the example is here which is more explicit